# SQL syntax 1.* What does this mean?

Tags: sql-server

I am looking at a piece of MSDN CAST and CONVERT article.
To simplify my question, consider:

```
select 1/3
```

and

```
select 1.*1/3
```

The first displays

> 0

and the second display the desired value

> 0.333

What is the second expression (1.*) called and I want further documentation.

Comment: What do you mean *"What is the first expression called"*? It's called division. In this case (in words): "one divided by three".

Comment: *"I want further documentation."* What was wrong with the documentation you found? SQL Server is very well documented.

Comment: I guess that the first snippet is doing division between two integers and returning an integer. The second snippet does division between a float (`1.0` or `1.` for short) and returns a float.

Comment: `1.` would be treated as a `numeric(1,0)`, @TedKleinBergman, not a `float`. [DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=45f5a72efe81e0a728681d4f2eef2e95) (`1e` on the other hand, would be treated as a `float`).

Comment: The expression isn't `1.*` it's `1.*1/3` In BODMAS terms, that could be written as `(1. * 1) / 3` ("one point (zero) times one, divided by three").

Comment: Personally, I think the article example would be clearer with an explict specification of the fractional value in the decimal literal: `select 1.0*1/3`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Larnu pointed out, 1. means a number that is 1, but due to the decimal point, its type is forced to be one that can store a decimal fraction, and not only the integer. The decimal part is not mandatory to be written out, so it is the same as writing 1.0. The * is simply a multiplication sign.

Regarding the end result: in almost every programming language, the type of the end result is determined by the types of the arguments without further investigation of possibly losing data. This means, that if the arguments are both integers, like at your first case, then the end result becomes an integer, so you will not have decimals. While at your second case, the expression contains 1., which results in a type mentioned above, so all the other arguments will be casted to that type so that arithmetic can be performed correctly. Well, at least this is my simplified version.

So this is not specific to CAST and CONVERT. Further documentation is on MSDN under data types. You would want to know when types are casted implicitly due to type precedence.

Comment: *"in almost every programming language"* SQL isn't a programming language though. ;) Though the point here applies to SQL as well, Query languages and Programming languages can behave *very* differently.

Comment: @Larnu You are right, this is very roughly explaining it with my "simplified version". As the OP wanted documentation, I just wanted to make an introduction why I say to read about data types & precedence - but going there and reading it is the right thing to do, for any language.

Comment: I know; just pointing it out. A lot of people make the "mistake" of treating SQL like a programming language; which is why they (foolishly) use iterative methods for things that *should* be using a data set approach.

Comment: I didn't know that it would be because of that... then I will never call SQL a programming language again! :)

Answer (score 0):

What we have here (in regards to the expression `1.*1/3`) boils down to 2 things: [Data Type Precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) and [Precision, scale, and Length](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/precision-scale-and-length-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

We'll start with the first item, Data Type Precedence. In the above expression you have 3 values, and 2 data types. `1.` a `numeric(1,0)`, `1` an int, and `3` also an `int`. As you have different data types here the data type with the **lower** precedence is casted "upwards". In this case `int` has a lower precedence that `numeric` and so `1` is casted "upwards" in the expression `1.*1`. Then `3` is also implicitly casted "upwards" when it is used by the divisor operator.

Now onto the precision scale and length. When performing arithmetic with a value with a scale/precision there are defined rules for the resulting value's scale and precision (in the above linked document). Firstly we have a multiplication, which uses the below formulas:

> Precision: `p1 + p2 + 1`
>   Scale: `s1 + s2`

*(`p1` refers to the precision of the value of the left of the expression, and `p2` the precision of the value on the right. `s1` and `s2` refer to the scale of the respective values.)*

So we have a `numeric(1,0)`, and an `int`, which'll be casted up to a `numeric(1,0)`. Therefore the resulting Precision will be `1 + 1 + 1` and the scale `0 + 0`. This results in a `numeric(3,0)` and can be confirmed with the below SQL:

```
SELECT system_type_name
FROM sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set(N'SELECT 1.*1',NULL,NULL);
```

Now onto the second part of the expression `/3`. We have a `numeric(3,0)` and a integer, which will now be implicitly casted to an `numeric(3,0)` as well. Then expression to calculate the precision and scale for division is different:

> Precision: `p1 - s1 + s2 + max(6, s1 + p2 + 1)`
>   Scale: `max(6, s1 + p2 + 1)`

Again, let's start with Precision. This results in the below expression (more complicated this time):

```
3 - 0 + 0 + max(6,0 + 3 + 1) = 3 + max(6,4) = 3 + 6 = 9
```

Now the scale:

```
max(6,0 + 3 + 1) = max(6,4) = 6
```

This results in a `numeric(9,6)`. This can also be verified with the below statement:

```
SELECT system_type_name
FROM sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set(N'SELECT 1.*1/3',NULL,NULL);
```

So, as a result, `SELECT 1.*1/3 = 0.333333` (not the `0.333` you have in your question).

As for your first expression, you only have `int` values, so an `int` will be returned. `1/3 = 0.3333~ = 0` as an `int`; as any decimal places are removed from the final value.